# How to change geolocation dynamically for google places api

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I am working on google places api in which first user selects city and enters address in text field to get locations specific for that city. For this i have used circle bounds.

Now when user changes cities i need to re-initialize google place api to apply new circle bounds. I have used following script.

```
<select name="cities" id="cities" onchange="initialize()">
        <option value="0">Select City</option>
        <option value="1" lat="40.7128" long="74.0059">Newyork</option>
        <option value="2" lat="34.0522" long="118.2437">Los Angeles</option>
        <option value="3" lat="42.3601" long="71.0589">Boston</option>
    </select>
    <input id="searchTextField" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Enter a location" autocomplete="on">

<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=places" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() 
    {
        var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
        var lat  = jQuery('#cities option:selected').attr('lat');
        var long = jQuery('#cities option:selected').attr('long');

        //alert(lat+' == '+long);

        var geolocation = {
            lat: lat,
            lng: long
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: geolocation,
            radius: 50
        });

        var options = {
            componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}
        };

        var temp = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        temp.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    }


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have mentioned the exact problem you were facing , that would have helped me think in the right direction but anyway your code looked normal so gave it a go and found these issues

**1**.When construction `LatLngLiteral` like this

```
   var geolocation = {
       lat: lat,
       lng: long
   };
```

when passing this to google function the values are expected to be numbers rather than string.May be you were getting this error *"not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number"* because `typeof lat` would give `"string"`

In order to conform you need to convert them using `parseFloat` .Now `typeof parseFloat(lat)` would give `"number"`

```
   var geolocation = {
       lat: parseFloat(lat),
       lng: parseFloat(long)
   };
```

**2**.Since US lies on west of GMT so all states have a negative longitude but you were using positive it should've been like this

```
    <option value="1" lat="40.7128" long="-74.0059">Newyork</option>
    <option value="2" lat="34.0522" long="-118.2437">Los Angeles</option>
    <option value="3" lat="42.3601" long="-71.0589">Boston</option>
```

Comment: I know that other results will show if area doesn't match but i need to change bounds anyway on change of select option. So that it should show results if area matches.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your problem earlier.I have edited the post

Comment: I have made changes you have suggested, like longitude and parseFloat change. But i am not getting any error in console. Its just that autocomplete doesn't work if i am trying to change bounds dynamically. When i provide static lat and long then it works fine.

Comment: Well can't say more coz I tried this myself and only those were the issues I could see. see http://jsbin.com/yisuralada/edit?js,output .Only thing I saw but didn't mention is that when autocomplete loads the first time selectbox is at "_select city_" having lat and long as _blank_ which might cause problem(rarely) if you are using loaders so try giving it some valid lat and long if it works then as a fix just remove this line `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);`

Comment: Yes, i forgot to remove `addDomListener`. Thanks, it works now.